# How to check if sklearn model is classifier or regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, classification, regression

Is there a simple way to check if a model instance solves a classification or regression task in the scikit-learn library?

Comment: This is a funny thing to want, can't really imagine a scenario in which that info is not available prior to actually fitting a model. I can only think of checking what kind of data the model is predicting

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `sklearn.base.is_classifier` and/or `is_regressor`:

```
from sklearn.base import is_classifier, is_regressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

models = [LinearRegression(), RandomForestClassifier(), RandomForestRegressor()]

for m in models:
    print(m.__class__.__name__, is_classifier(m), is_regressor(m))
```

Output:

```
# model_name is_classifier is_regressor
LinearRegression False True
RandomForestClassifier True False
RandomForestRegressor False True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know it existed in the base package.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you ask this because you have a serialized model whose type you do not know. Open the file and do

```
mlType = type(variable_name)
```

where variable_name is the handle of your de-serialized model.

output e.g.

```
class 'sklearn.linear_model.base.LinearRegression'
```